# I want to add the ID in the API

Tags: vue.js, axios, put

[**API**](https://ipAddress/api/journals/v1/indexing/journalID/indexingId.json)

In my `Indexin.vue`.

```html
<template>
 <div
  class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3 m-3 card"
  v-for="data in indexingList"
  :key="data.indexing_id">
  <div>
   <base-button
    type="primary"
    size="sm"
    @click="deleteIndexing(data.indexing_id)"
    class="ml-4"
    >Delete</base-button
   >
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

method: deleteIndexing: function() {
this.api.putData('indexing/'+store.state.journalId,
this.indexingList.indexing_id).then((res)=> { console.log(res.data) },(error)=>
{ console.log(error) }) },
```

Here in my `api.js`.

```js
putData (action, data) { let url = `${BASE_URL}` url += action + '.json' return
instance.put(url, data) },
```

And the Error which I'm facing.

```
Error: http://ipAddress/api/journals/v1/indexing/1.json' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.
```

I'm passing`'indexing/'+store.state.journalId`as an argument against`putData`function's action parameter. That is showing in the IP address. But I have to pass `indexing_id` as a second argument in the `api`. I passed `this.indexingList.indexing_id` as a second argument against `putData`. But in the error it's showing `1.json` in the end. 1 is journal ID, not the indexing ID. It's not taking the second argument. `indexing_id` has been written in the server side, just I have to pass in the API. But it's not taking, and I'm getting the error.

Comment: The API is 404 anyway.

Comment: Yes, just marked it as a duplicate.